# Customize jdbcexception error message

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-security

I have a java web application which is deployed on a linux server using tomcat and mysql. Most of the time in the morning , When i try to login , it gives the following error : "The last packet successfully received from the server was 60,244,374 milliseconds ago...." This is a common issue and i have already insert some properties in my tomcat connection and i need to wait for testing. Meanwhile , I want to customize this error message to "Server is down". Can someone tell me how to catch this exception?
Note that i use spring security for authentication and for database : hibernate and jpa (jndi)Please find attached error message. This error message is too complex for user!  [image: error message]